# Cytoscape.js : right click event on nodes

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to add a right click event on the nodes, but it looks like the framework isn't capturing these events. This event is only fired when I left click:

```
cy.on('mousedown', (event, node) => {         
    console.log(event.originalEvent);
});
```

From the original event we could filter on the button we are interested in?

Comment: What is your exact question? If you want to add a right click event on nodes, you can use cy.on('cxttap', "node", function(event) { });

Comment: the questios wasn't more complicated ;-) worked , thanks

Comment: it was a rfa :-(

Comment: Please post your answer below and accept it yourself, that way others get the answer more easily :) Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add a right click event on nodes, you can use

`cy.on('cxttap', "node", function(event) { });`

Comment: that's a bit like cheating the answer ;-)